# Application Pool error Event code: 3008 Exception type: ConfigurationErrorsException

Tags: .net, iis

I created a ASP.net WebAPI service application. I published it on Server 2008 R2 but I'm getting an error when I call site.

By the way, same build pack is working on an other Server 2008 R2.

There is no different configuration settings between that two operating systems, I checked it.  And all .net version are ok and updated.

I'm searching issue on internet, I found much more information about about event log 3008 but Exception type and Exception Message are different not like mine.

What is wrong ?

> Keywords :Classic    Date and Time :31.12.2015 09:25:12
>   Source    :ASP.NET 4.0.30319.0    Event ID :1310     Task Category :Web
>   Event
>
> Event code: 3008 Event message: A configuration error has occurred.
>   Event time: 31.12.2015 09:25:12 Event time (UTC): 31.12.2015 07:25:12
>   Event ID: 03d0578e740f41dc93276cc1ec01d333 Event sequence: 1 Event
>   occurrence: 1 Event detail code: 0
>
> Application information: Application domain:
>   /LM/W3SVC/4/ROOT-28-130960203063596353 Trust level: Full Application
>   Virtual Path: / Application Path: C:\WebRoot\Applications\wky\app\
>   Machine name: TF2APPSRV1
>
> Process information: Process ID: 9820 Process name: w3wp.exe Account
>   name: IIS APPPOOL\TOFAS_wky_app
>
> Exception information: Exception type: ConfigurationErrorsException
>   Exception message: External component has thrown an exception. at
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String
>   assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) at
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory()
>   at
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo
>   ai) at System.Web.Configuration.AssemblyInfo.get_AssemblyInternal() at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection
>   compConfig) at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies()
>   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String
>   preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() at
>   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager
>   appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory
>   configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters,
>   PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException)
>
> External component has thrown an exception. at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String
>   codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks) at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String
>   codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks) at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName
>   assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks) at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr
>   pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean
>   forIntrospection) at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String
>   assemblyString) at
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String
>   assemblyName, Boolean starDirective)
>
> Request information: Request URL: http://localhost:3340/ Request path:
>   / User host address: ::1 User: Is authenticated: False Authentication
>   Type: Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\TOFAS_wky_app
>
> Thread information: Thread ID: 114 Thread account name: IIS
>   APPPOOL\TOFAS_wky_app Is impersonating: False Stack trace: at
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String
>   assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) at
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory()
>   at
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo
>   ai) at System.Web.Configuration.AssemblyInfo.get_AssemblyInternal() at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection
>   compConfig) at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies()
>   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String
>   preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() at
>   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager
>   appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory
>   configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters,
>   PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException)

Comment: Keyword in above exception is "throwOnFileNotFound". Looks like there is some assembly missing from bin directory/gac or file is present but with different version or built for different platform i.e. x86/x64. You may also like to verify assemblies mentioned in web.config are present in bin/gac and with correct version.

Comment: @PankajKapare thank you , i'm controlling.